# What might be causing MySQL replication error 1594 (Relay log read failure, corrupted logs)?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqlbinlog

I have 3 similar master-slave replication setups and only 1 of them fails daily, sometimes a couple times a day. Every time it's slave's relay log that is corrupted. So all it takes to recover is to reset slave and run again.
Internet is full off articles on how to recover if mysql relay logs get corrupted, anyone knows why it might be happening? And how to prevent it from happening?